# Calling unmanaged c++ code from managed C# code to generate offline domain join blob

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, native, managed

I am writing a piece of program that generates `Offline Domain Join` blob and saves it for future use. This action can be done using command prompt. Below is a sample command that will generate the mentioned file and save it on D drive:

`D:\djoin.exe /REUSE /PROVISION /DOMAIN MyDomain.MyCompany.com /MACHINE "user1-pc" /SAVEFILE blob.txt`

More information: [Offline Domain Join (Djoin.exe) Step-by-Step Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/offline-domain-join-djoin-step-by-step(v=ws.10).aspx)

Now, I want to add a method to my program (written with C#) to does this functionality for me.

One of the problems here is, the API that Microsoft has provided is a C++ API. I have tried to use the API in managed code using `PInvoke`. Below is the code I have written.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestBlob
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String domain = "MyDomain.MyCompany.com";
            String machineName = "user1-pc";
            String machineAccoutOU = null;
            String dcName = "MyDomain";
            uint options = 1;
            IntPtr provisionBinData = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr provisionBinDataSize = IntPtr.Zero;
            string blob = string.Empty;
            IntPtr pProvisionTextData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(blob);

            uint status = ODJNativeMethods.NetProvisionComputerAccount(domain, machineName, machineAccoutOU, dcName, options, ref provisionBinData, ref provisionBinDataSize, ref pProvisionTextData);

            Console.WriteLine(status);
            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pProvisionTextData));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("Netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint NetProvisionComputerAccount([In] String lpDomain,
                                                              [In] String lpMachineName,
                                                              [In] String lpMachineAccountOU,
                                                              [In] String lpDcName,
                                                              [In] uint dwOptions,
                                                              [In] [Out] ref IntPtr pProvisionBinData,
                                                              [In] [Out] ref IntPtr pdwProvisionBinDataSize,
                                                              [In] [Out] ref IntPtr pProvisionTextData);
    }
}
```

When I run the application, it always returns 87 (shows on console), which after a quick search turns out to be an error message: The parameter is invalid.

What am I doing wrong here? Are my PInvoke types not the correct ones corresponding to native language API?

Comment: Your last three options appear to be incorrect - I think these should be `ref byte[]`, `ref uint`, and `ref string`, or just 3 `IntPtr`s..

Comment: Actually they were all IntPtr first, same error message. What about the marshaling? Have I done that correctly? Is it even needed?

Comment: @yaakov I only need to get the blob file with my C# application. Do you know how I can leverage this native DLL and use in a C# program? There is literally zero sample code online to refer to! I've been trying and searching for hours!

Comment: At the moment you can't tell whether the error is in the data you pass to the function, or your p/invoke handling. Next step is to narrow that down by writing a C++ program, compiled against the official SDK, that succeeds. At that point you will have a template for data that is known to work. If your C# variant fails with the same data then you know the issus is in your pinvoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 last parameters are declared *out*, which means you must not initialize them, but pass correct pointer so the function can allocate things for you.

Also, from what I understand reading the function doc, the binary one and the string one are mutually exclusive, so let's say you want to get back the binary one, then you can define the API like this ([in] are usually implicit):

```
    [DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int NetProvisionComputerAccount(
        string lpDomain,
        string lpMachineName,
        string lpMachineAccountOU,
        string lpDcName,
        int dwOptions,
        out IntPtr pProvisionBinData,
        out int pdwProvisionBinDataSize,
        IntPtr pProvisionTextData);
```

Note the function does not use SetLastError, so don't declare it in the declaration.

And here is how to call it:

```
        string domain = "MyDomain.MyCompany.com";
        string machineName = "user1-pc";
        string machineAccoutOU = null;
        string dcName = "MyDomain";
        // I suggest you don't use hardcoded values to be nice with readers
        const int NETSETUP_PROVISION_DOWNLEVEL_PRIV_SUPPORT = 1;

        int status = NetProvisionComputerAccount(
            domain,
            machineName,
            machineAccoutOU,
            dcName,
            NETSETUP_PROVISION_DOWNLEVEL_PRIV_SUPPORT,
            out IntPtr binData, // let the system allocate the binary thing
            out int binDataSize, // this will be the size of the binary thing
            IntPtr.Zero); // we don't use this one here, pass null
```

I can't test further (I get error 1354 which I suppose is normal in my context).

Note the doc doesn't say anything about deallocating what the function allocates (if it allocates something? there are some rare Windows API that use static buffers they own). I think you're supposed to call NetApiBufferFree on binData once all work is done, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This actually works :) and thanks for mentioning deallocation! I'll take a look to see how I should handle that.

Answer (score -1):

It could be the encoding of your text file - if you have saved it as ANSI and consuming it as Unicode, it might not work.

Use these statements corresponding to your above code:

```
IntPtr pProvisionTextData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(blob);
```

and

```
[DllImport("user32", CharSet=CharSet::Ansi)]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Win32 function definition is `LPCWSTR`, which is unicode.

Comment: Yeah. I still tried it but didn't go through. Thanks for the comment.